# Break Apart String with Regex

Tags: regex, splunk

I have a Splunk query that looks like

`100.100.100.1 - - [11/Oct/2019:17:49:47 +0000] "GET /someroute/rest/endpoint?param=2019-09-25 HTTP/1.1"`

and I would really like to be able to break this apart using only regex so that I can get the

`GET` and `/someroute/rest/endpoint` as two separate groups. Ignoring everything from the query parameters and on.

Comment: 1. There isn't a `POST` in your question, so I assume you mean `GET`. 2. Are you looking for the URL with or without parameters - you listed without, but based on the post/get issue, I'm concerned you're looking for full path?

Comment: @ctwheels I am looking for only the request type, whether that is GET or POST and the I only want the path up to where the query parameters begin. I don't care for the query parameters in this case.

Comment: Does `"(GET|POST)\s+(\/[^?"]*)` work for you?

Comment: It still contains this part: `HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Please check to ensure you copied it properly: https://regex101.com/r/VYz3TB/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern :

**Regex :**

```
^.*?(GET|POST).*?([\/\w]+)
```

**Demo :**
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/I78MQv/1)

if you want the param included you can use :
**Regex**

```
^.*?(GET|POST).*?([\/\w]+)(\?param=([^\s]+))?
```

**Demo :**
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/I78MQv/2)